# How can I store multiple separate instances of the same class in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I have a class `Command`...

```
class Command(ABC)
    """
    Command
    """
    keys = []

    def __call__(self, args) -> bool:
        return True
```

And a class `CommandCenter`...

```
class CommandCenter():
    commands = []

    def add_command(self, command):
        self.commands.append(command)

    def find_command(self, key):
        for i, c in enumerate(self.commands):
            if key in self.commands[i].keys:
                return c

    def execute_command(self, command_info)
        command = self.find_command(command_info[0])
        return command(command_info[1])
```

They have more methods than this, but the idea is that I am using these classes to maintain a set of commands that can be queried by keys, and executed using arguments. It's a trivial thing that can be done without classes, however, my goal is to reuse the CommandCenter class and inheret from it to also handle command modifiers, and the commands being classes should just allows me to keep the keys, docs, and methods used by the commands all bundled nicely.

I had it working just fine, but the issues started when I attempted to test creating a second CommandCenter.

I currently have a main body that looks something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = CommandCenter()
    commands.add_command(HelpCommand())

    some_other_center = CommandCenter()
    some_other_center.add_command(ExitCommand())
```

What I expect this to do is create 2 different object instances of `CommandCenter`, add the help command to the first instance, and add the exit command to the second instance. However, when I run `help exit` from `commands`, it successfully prints the exit doc string. Which means when I call `.add_command` on either CommandCenter, it is adding the command to both.

When I comment out the lines of `some_other_center`, then call `help exit` from `commands`, I get the error I am expecting. As well, if I try to call `help exit` on `some_other_center`, even though I don't expect it to have the `HelpCommand`, it works just fine. Even if I ignore my `.add_command` method and append to the object's commands list, it still adds each command to both.

Is there some other object type I should be using to replicate the functionality of C classes?

**Edit:**
I did some further testing based on a comment, and it appears that if the class is responsible for a list, it needs to be in the `__init__` method. Why is this exactly?

If I do this...

```
class SomeClass()
    value = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

object1 = SomeClass()
object1.value = 6

object2 = SomeClass()
object2.value = 12
```

and I print this out, I get this:

```
6
12
```

However, if I do this...

```
class SomeClass()
    value = []

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

object1 = SomeClass()
object1.value.append(6)

object2 = SomeClass()
object2.value.append(12)
```

and I print that out, I get this:

```
[6,12]
[6,12]
```

But if I do this...

```
class SomeClass()
    def __init__(self)
        self.value = []

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

object1 = SomeClass()
object1.value.append(6)

object2 = SomeClass()
object2.value.append(12)
```

I end up with this:

```
[6]
[12]
```

Comment: Do you not think commands = [] needs to be in init method?

Comment: In your code `commands` is class variable shared by all object of this class.

Comment: Yes  exactly @YuriGinsburg so you would be saying in init constructor self.commands = []

Comment: A use case for a Class level variable could be to maintain a registry of all objects in memory - say based on a name string as a dictionary key and the value a reference to the object itself. An old school C style use case would have been reference counting before you had the likes of garbage collection etc. By placing the self prefix in the init constructor you are saying this is per instance. The commands = [] in your initial example is outside the constructor and so is by default a class level variable.

Comment: @JGFMK That makes sense, the only part I am still confused about is if you look at my edit, when I make an integer as a class level variable, it is not shared. It's only shared if it's a list. As far as I am aware, both lists and integers are mutable, right? Why do they act differently in this way? For clarification, I am setting both class objects before doing any of the prints in every case.

Comment: the `__init__()` method is the **constructor**. all languages that have classes will have a constructor for the class...  really, this is a separate question to the original question.

Comment: @D.L I have been trying to reword the question, originally I didn't understand the actual problem. When you set integer variables in a class outside of `__init___` they work as you'd expect. I guess because integers are immutable? I assumed `__init__` was an optional method for doing things such as defining state based on parameters, and that if you didn't need external parameters, setting variables in the class space, which are then accessed through the self reference, would be inherently copied on class instantiation.

Comment: Probably down to value as an int primitive by value reference vs value as a list being stored as a by reference (recall objects - such as list are by reference)

Comment: i.e. when value is a list, it's a pointer the same area of memory because the name value  is a by reference alias across instances of the class, vs primitives that have their own individual memory allocations -being by value. https://pynative.com/python-class-variables/#:~:text=Understand%20Class%20Variables-,Create%20Class%20Variables,constructor%20method%20and%20other%20methods.

Comment: this video might help you for a starter:  https://youtube.com/live/SNEIuMd5aJA